# Project runs when built from Xcode but crashes when built from Command Line (React Native)

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, build, google-material-icons

When running react-native run-ios, I get the following warning:

```
** BUILD SUCCEEDED **



The following commands produced analyzer issues:
    Analyze Base/RCTModuleMethod.mm normal x86_64
    Analyze RCTNetInfo.m normal x86_64
(2 commands with analyzer issues)
```

Whenever I try to open my app on the simulator started from the command line, it crashes.
But when building the project from XCode everything seems to work fine.

What's going on? I'd like to start it from the command line so I could use react-native debugging tools :(

Alternatively does anyone know how to get logs for this crash on loading screen error?

---

React Native Version:

react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.57.8

Comment: check once if this module is present inside  `node_modules`.

Comment: @abhinandansharma are you talking about the react-native node module? Cause that's where "RCTModuleMethod.m" and "RCTNetInfo.m" are. Yes, the module is present.